# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**i cant open  mysql in ubuntu 16.04**
when i type mysql in my terminal

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

this show up
and i try mysqld and its give me this ...

the code error

```
    Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found.
mhadi@mhadi:~/Desktop$ service mysql start
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
mhadi@mhadi:~/Desktop$ sudo mysqld start
170719 14:33:01 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.0.24-MariaDB-7) starting as process 14463 ...
170719 14:33:01 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mhadi.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
170719 14:33:01 [ERROR] Aborting

170719 14:33:01 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: check directory /var/lib/mysql/. if not exist mkdir /var/lib/mysql

Comment: I know it's a bit of a sledgehammer suggestion - but try uninstalling MySQL and re-install it.  Make sure this works first.

Comment: i try that to but it didn't  work

Comment: `ln -s` will help - create a symbolic link from the file (can't remember where it lives) and link it to where it tries to look for it